# Add files from other folders (libraries, ...) to git

Tags: git, shared-libraries

How can one add files from another folder to current git?
I have files in a library which is not located in my solution folder, but I want it to be version controlled using `git`.
I should have a duplicate copy of library inside my solution?

Comment: You can't without bringing them in to your project repository.  You will get the `fatal: 'some/folder/file.ext' is outside repository.`  This has nothing to do with Visual Studio, it has to do with git and how git works.  Of course this comment is making a ton of assumptions, as you give no detail as to what those other folders relationship is to your repository, and the question is pretty vague.

Comment: I have files in a library which is not located in my solution folder, but I want it to be version controlled using git. I should have a duplicate copy of library inside my solution?

Comment: You can do this, without a duplicate copy inside your solution, and it wouldn't even be that hard, but are you certain you really want to do it?  What you're describing here is packaging and installation management, and there are already tools for that.

Comment: As a separate take on this, who controls the folders containing these libraries?  If they're outside your repo hierarchy, how'd the libraries get there in the first place?  Unclear responsibility for content versioning is a.k.a. "dll hell" and many other names in all its related forms. Windows is far from the only place you can find horrors like that, and what you're asking for looks exactly like the first stepping stones on the path to the demon plane where they all live.